# What is the main "stack overflow" site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Does "Stack Overflow" have an overall main site that ties all of the other sites together, like being able to see all questions, all answers and just peruse data from all of them?

Comment: Do you mean [StackExchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Do you mean stack overflow (which is just for specific programing questions) or all of StackExchange (which includes sites on gardening, games, etc)?

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was wondering. That is exactly what I was hoping they had, Thanks!

Comment: [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/) ties all of the sites together, but it doesn't give you a way to "see all questions, all answers and just peruse data from all of them?" - use Google for that.

Comment: @Oded isn't [this list](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) pretty close?

Comment: @3ventic I think thats just a "sample", it must be because it would go past at a terrifying rate otherwise (and it says so)

Comment: I am not hard to please. Just seeing a place where all of them exist, is good enough for me. At least I can see all available sites, and basic stats. Now I just need to figure out how to tell which stackexchange sites I have not joined yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where you can see all questions, all answers and just peruse data from all of them?

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Oded You sort of get that, ish, with http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime and such. Not really, but its on the way. And you can get other questions with http://stackexchange.com/filters/89799/my-filter

Comment: @RichardTingle - I'd say that [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) is closer ;)

Comment: @Oded Won't find any arguments there, thats a lot less ish

Comment: Oded, tanks that's even better.